# Declaring DTD Element With ANY and required elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, dtd

I would like to describe in a DTD an element **MYELEMENT** that must composed by **elementA**, **elementB** and **any** other element. For that purpose I tried the syntax:

```
<!ELEMENT MYELEMENT (elementA | elementB | ANY)*>
```

But this does not work when an element other than elementA or elementB occurs. Can somebody help with the right syntax with DTD?

Can this be done using XSD schema?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you say "MYELEMENT ... must [be] composed by elementA, elementB and any other element", do you mean

- (A) An occurrence of MYELEMENT may have zero or more children; each child may be named `elementA`, `elementB`, or anything else.

or

- (B) Each occurrence of MYELEMENT should have at least one child named `elementA`, at least one named `elementB`, in either order, and may have other children as well.

or

- (C) Each occurrence of MYELEMENT should have exactly one child named `elementA`, exactly one named `elementB`, in either order, and may have other children as well.

If in DTDs the keyword `ANY` were a sort of wildcard which matched any element regardless of name, then the content model you show would match possibility (A).  That's not what the keyword means, though, so the declaration you show doesn't do what you want:  the declaration you give simply means that any occurrence of MYELEMENT may contain zero or more elements, as long as each child of MYELEMENT is named either `elementA` or `elementB` or `ANY`.

If (A) is what you want, though, there is no need to specify `elementA` or `elementB` at all; all you need is a wildcard that matches any element.  DTDs have no such wildcard, though if you don't mind allowing character data as well as child elements, the declaration

```
<!ELEMENT MYELEMENT ANY >
```

would come close to your spec.  In XSD, you'd use the `xsd:any` wildcard.

If what you want is (B) or (C), then XSD 1.0 can come close; you can allow the elements you name, as well as any elements in a different namespace, using a wildcard with `namespace="##other"`.

If the order carries no meaning, you will find the content model easier to specify if you specify an arbitrary sequence.  (Variable sequence is necessary when it conveys information; when it doesn't convey information, it only complicates life and opens a covert channel.)